# How can I disable the multitouch capabilities in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

How to disable the multitouch capabilities in new iPhone application?

Comment: what do you mean by lock? disable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-touch tracking is not enabled by default, so in effect you need not do anything. See "multipleTouchEnabled" in the documentation for UIView.